# Send temperature sensor module messages from lower layer device to upper layer device in Azure IoT

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Scenario is to build a hierarchy of IoT devices and at the upper layer I need to receive the messages send from the child device. I have tried giving BrokeredEndpoint at the routes in the deployment.json file in the upper layer at the input.
My code
"routes": {
"pythondepmoduleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/pythondepmodule/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
"sensorTopythondepmodule": "FROM /messages/modules/childdeviceModule/outputs/output INTO BrokeredEndpoint("/modules/pythondepmodule/inputs/input1")"
},
At the upper layer(deployment.json file)
"routes": {
"childdeviceModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/childdeviceModule/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
"sensorTochilddeviceModule": "FROM /messages/modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint("/modules/childdeviceModule/inputs/input1")"
},
At the lower layer

Comment: The configuration you are trying to do is applicable for [Establishing routes between modules on an IoT Edge device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-1.4). Can you clarify if that is what you are trying to achieve? Can you share more details on what your edge devices are and what kind of telemetry data are you trying to transfer from your lower layer device to your parent edge device

Comment: If you need to establish communication between two different IoT edge devices, you will have to refer these resources - [How to create nested edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-connect-downstream-iot-edge-device?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal) [Connect a downstream device to an IoT Edge gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-connect-downstream-device?source=recommendations&view=iotedge-1.4)